# How do you input a string inside each block of memory in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to access strings from an array, just like one can access integers from arrays, say `A={1,2,3}` then upon calling `A[0]` one would get `1`. Similarly what should be done for strings such that `A={a,b,c}` so upon calling `A[0]` I get `a`.

I tried this for the input,

```
char in[1000];
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    in[i]="A";
    printf("in is %f",in[i]);
}
```

but I am getting a warning `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Comment: try to change `printf("in is %f",in[i])` to `printf("in is %c",in[i])`

Comment: You are assigning a character, try to change in[i]="A" to in[i]='A' and then use %c for printf.

Comment: @TychoTheTaco It removed an other warning, but I am still getting the `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast` warning. Upon running the code I am getting `in is N` five times

Comment: @Aradhna Thank you! that worked

Comment: `char in[1000] = { 'a', 'b', 'c'};
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    printf("in[%d] is %c\n", i, in[i]);
}`

Comment: Can you please my post as the answer?

Comment: `char in[1000];` <- in is an array of 1000 characters, not 1000 strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making a character array, you need to supply a character value to it.

Change your code to

```
in[i]='A'
printf("in is %c",in[i]);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%s` for strings not `%f`.

- %s - Strings (character arrays in case of C)
- %c - Characters
- %f - floats
- %d - int
- %ls - long int

Your example :

```
int i=0;
char in[1000];
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    in[i]='A';
    printf("in is %c\n",in[i]);
}
```

Sample code : [example](http://ideone.com/vm05go)